# Method for User Input in Swift for iOS App Development

Tags: ios, swift

I have referred the Apple's Swift Programming Language book, and it is of no help.

```
  var fh = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    if let data = fh.availableData
    {
        var str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
```

[image: The Screenshot of my error]

Comment: if you become little bit clear about what you want to ask people will help you.

Comment: I'll edit with what I've implemented in my code.

Comment: Oops. I'd have to insert object. instead i tried with a variable.

Answer (score 1):

There is more to it than that. Typically in iOS development, you'll have a `UITextView` become first responder. A responder is an object (event handling object) that can respond to events and handle them. Once you make a UI element become first responder, you can accomplish what you want. From there, the keyboard appears and the user enters something.

Once that's done, you can resign the first responder and look at the text and use it however you want. Some rough code for this process looks like this:

```
//Create a label
let tv = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100))
self.view.addSubView(tv)

//Tell iOS we want this to handle text input
tv.becomeFirstResponder()

//User enters text, tell iOS we're done handling text input events and print input
tv.resignFirstResponder()
println(tv.text)
```

A good resource for input in iOS: [User Input in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

Comment: Here, UITextView is to add in some text space right? what about Table cells ? how to add text from keyboards to table cell?

Comment: You'd have to add _some_ type of UI element that can handle text input. UITableViewCells can't on their own, but you can add a UITextView to a cell, something like cell.contentView.addSubView(textView)